# AJAX form communication, displaying resulting messages - how to?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm new to the ajax scene and slowly getting the hang of it, sort of. I've built a fairly functional form, with exception to a few details which I'm getting ironed out. One of which is the reason to this question.

I have a form which does successfully update via ajax to a mysql database by the process of html -> ajax -> php -> mysql. However currently there is absolutely no communication messages or indicators being returned from the php to the html, to indicate success or error. Being quite new to using ajax, some help is appreciated.

Technologies in use: jQuery, JavaScript, html, php

HTML form (a section of it, not the full form as that would be unnecessary):

```
<form id="<?=$applicationKey?>" name="<?=$applicationKey?>" action="./post.<?=$appNo.'.'.$applicationKey?>.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$sessionToken?>">
<input type="hidden" name="uID" value="<?=$uID?>">
<input type="hidden" name="uaID" value="<?=$uaID?>">
<input type="hidden" name="appID" value="<?=$appID?>">

 <table style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
  <tbody><tr>
   <td class="tright" style="width: 265px;">Name of the Applicant's Organisation:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_1" name="input_1_1" placeholder="Name of the Applicant's Organisation" maxlength="64" value="<?=$input_1_1?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_1"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_1" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Contact Person:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_2" name="input_1_2" placeholder="Contact Person" maxlength="64" value="<?=$input_1_2?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_2"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_2" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Telephone (Landline):</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_3" name="input_1_3" placeholder="Telephone (Landline)" maxlength="22" value="<?=$input_1_3?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_3"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_3" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Telephone (Mobile):</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_4" name="input_1_4" placeholder="Telephone (Mobile)" maxlength="22" value="<?=$input_1_4?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_4"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_4" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Email:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_5" name="input_1_5" placeholder="Email" maxlength="64" value="<?=$input_1_5?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_5"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_5" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Fax:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="input_1_6" name="input_1_6" placeholder="Fax" maxlength="22" value="<?=$input_1_6?>" required><span id="resultImg_1_6"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_6" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="tright">Address:</td>
   <td><textarea id="input_1_7" name="input_1_7" placeholder="Address" maxlength="120" required><?=$input_1_7?></textarea><span id="resultImg_1_7"></span><br>
   <div id="errorText_1_7" class="errorOutput"></div></td>
  </tr></tbody>
 </table>
```

The included js file looks like this (for this part of the form):

```
function doSend_1_1() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_1', $('#input_1_1').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_2() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_2', $('#input_1_2').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_3() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_3', $('#input_1_3').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_4() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_4', $('#input_1_4').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_5() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_5', $('#input_1_5').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_6() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_6', $('#input_1_6').serialize());
}

function doSend_1_7() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_7', $('#input_1_7').serialize());
}

$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#input_1_1").blur(doSend_1_1);
    $("#input_1_2").blur(doSend_1_2);
    $("#input_1_3").blur(doSend_1_3);
    $("#input_1_4").blur(doSend_1_4);
    $("#input_1_5").blur(doSend_1_5);
    $("#input_1_6").blur(doSend_1_6);
    $("#input_1_7").blur(doSend_1_7);
})
```

And finally, the receiving php section that deals with the section of the form shown here, looks like this:

```
<?php
// include the funcky stuff
include './conf/Funcs.php';
include './conf/DBconfig.php';

// GET the constants
$token = $_GET['token'];
$appID = $_GET['appID'];
$ident = $_GET['ident'];

// =================== TAB 1 ===================
// organisation
if(($ident) == "input_1_1") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_1'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `organisation` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// contactPerson
if(($ident) == "input_1_2") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_2'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `contactPerson` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// phoneLandline
if(($ident) == "input_1_3") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_3'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `phoneLandline` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_INT, 22);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// phoneMobile
if(($ident) == "input_1_4") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_4'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `phoneMobile` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_INT, 22);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// email
if(($ident) == "input_1_5") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_5'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `email` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// fax
if(($ident) == "input_1_6") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_6'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `fax` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_INT, 22);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

// address
if(($ident) == "input_1_7") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_7'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `address` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 128);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
```

etc and onwards for the rest of the form that I've not quoted in here. I realise that there is some GET action happening in this - and that is ok. I want some stuff done by GET as opposed to POST for security reasons (I've not shown that here in this example, it's not relevant). As I mentioned before this is my first ajax work, so I know it's not going to be pristine. I'm ok about that right now and don't really want to be shown several different ways to re-write it. I just need to know how to send back a message originating from the php that tells the html whether success of failure happened, and if failure, why. I have the respective error output div's prepared in the html and I have a span also prepared for a nice image to correspond (tick or bouncy arrow to draw attention to something needing fixing). A demonstration of how to validate and send the message back - with JSON(?) would be helpful. I've read a lot about JSON being good for this, though I've not got my head around it yet.

Comment: Did you try inspecting the communication using firebug / the chrome developer integration network tab? I think this little thingy comes in very handy for you also see failed requests on the server (caused by a wrong location string of your ajax php file). 
Depeding on which jquery function you use to get data from the server, you wont see any result either if there are any errors in formatting (for example when you load data using $.getJson and the result won't be valid json (for example due an mysql error))

Comment: @serjoscha Firebug does not report any problems simply because there is no problem as it is, right now. I do not know how or where to set up the communication factors on the things I'm wanting, this is the question.

Comment: @Cassandra This is a community website where [content can be edited for review, etc by other users.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) Your commentary on editing is not appropriate for your question. If you have concerns about editing, then [take it up on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Placing it inside of the question is not the proper place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, it's not as complicated as it might seem. When you handle an ajax request in php, anything that you output in the php will be returned and you can use it in your javascript.

So if you have `echo 'hello';` in your php script, hello will be sent back to your javascript. You can output pretty much anything.

JSON is a convenient format for the output, because it's very easy to handle in both languages. If you have an associative array in your php with the data you want to send back, you can simply do:

```
$return = json_encode($my_data);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $return;
```

You can then get that data in your javascript:

```
$.post( 'handler.php', function( data ) {
  // data now has the data structure from your php in it, ready to use.
});
```

Here is an example of sending some data back from your php (I'm sure you will do it a bit different in practice, but just an example fitted around the existing code):

```
$error_message = '';
if(($ident) == "input_1_1") {
    $userInput = $_POST['input_1_1'];
    if(($userInput == "") || ($userInput == " ") || ($userInput == NULL)) { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_ConSupAp SET `organisation` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        if( $stmt->execute() ) {
            $error_message = 'Success';
        } else {
            $error_message = 'Error';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}

$return_data = array( 'errorText' => $error_message );
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

And you could then use that in your javascript to display the message:

```
function doSend_1_1() {
    $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_1', $('#input_1_1').serialize()).done(function(data) {
        $('#errorText_1_1').html(data.errorText);
    });
}
```

In an example this simple, it's unnecessary to use JSON - we could just send the text back. But hopefully it shows how you could send more data as needed. Anything you put in `$return_data` would be sent to your javascript .done function.

Try this to specify that the response will be in json, so that you can use the returned data directly:

```
function doSend_1_1() {
        $.post('./post.4.ConSupAp.php?appID=' + (appID) + '&ident=input_1_1', 
                $('#input_1_1').serialize(),
                function(data) {
                    $('#errorText_1_1').html(data.errorText);
                },
                'json' );
}
```

Comment: @James Thanks James, are you able to give me a little demo code using my above code, so I can get a feel for how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: @Cassandra, I updated my answer with a rough example, which would just send a success or failure message back depending on the $stmt->execute return. Not how you're likely to handle it in reality, but hopefully shows the mechanism for returning and handling data.

Comment: @James Huge thank you James, it's very appreciated. :)

Comment: Though it doesn't quite work, for some reason. Firebug does not give me an error as to why... the response is as expected but nothing appears in the <div id="errorText_1_1" class="errorOutput"></div> at all. I cannot figure out why. :/

Comment: Try doing a console.dir(data) just before $('#errorText_1_1').html(data.errorText); to check that data is coming back in the expected form.

Comment: I don't suppose we need some sort of json decode happening in order for the JS to be able to work with what returns? It seems to be working perfectly from what Firebug tells me but nothing gets displayed, which is kinda weird.

Comment: Yes that could well be the problem, and there is a parseJSON but usually it is decoded implicitly. However, we haven't told it to expect json (I sent a content type header in the first example but not the longer one). You can also specify in $.post what sort of response to expect, which I think it clearer - and that way it should automatically decode it.

Comment: Added an alternate version of doSend_1_1 which specifies that the return data type is json.

Comment: New alternative version works perfectly, as expected and desired. Awesome help there James, it's greatly appreciated. :)